# Facebook Login: having several site URLs for dev, test and prod

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I've got a dev server on localhost, a test server on a dedicated server and (soon) a prod server on another dedicated server. The app I'm developing uses Facebook Open Graph API.

On `developers.facebook.com/apps/myAppId/summary`, section `Select how your app integrates with Facebook` > `Website with Facebook Login` > `Site URL`, I need then to add several URLs (one for each of my server). How should I process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's currently no distinction in the API between production, QA, testing environments for a single App.

You need to use a different App ID for each environment

Comment: I upload every single time :) ha ha

Comment: @Jashwant Yeah, it's one of the possible solutions, after all :)

Comment: Site URL can be multiple sub domains, you can use dev.toto.com as your dev web site, just change DNS on your local /Etc/hosts or hosts.txt file.